# Zooming out combines annotations

Tags: ios, mapkit

Could someone share with me (at least as a general algorithm) how one would go about combining map annotations, that are within close proximity to each other, into 1 annotation upon scaling/zooming out of the map. So if the user has many different map annotations displayed in a region only one would appear after zooming out a certain distance (I'll figure out the distance that'll look visually "correct" at some point later on). I want to try adding a number inside the tag representing how many combined annotations are within that region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement map clustering. Here is a nice [read up](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=en) from Google, also check a sample [app with clustering](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoMap/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks a lot.